# Hide Div Element When User Scroll Down in Angular

Tags: angular

Is there any angular way to hide the div element when user scrolls down and show that element again when user scroll on to top the page.

Comment: Could you please share sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here below is the working code link shared, I have created one example for the same. Using **pageYOffset of windows** to hide div element on scroll down.

**[Hide Div Element When User Scroll Down in Angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-37kgcg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**add in component.ts file**

`import {HostListener } from '@angular/core';`
 `@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) getScrollHeight(event) {
   if(window.pageYOffset> 0 )
    this.offsetFlag = false;
   else
     this.offsetFlag = true;
}`

**add offsetFlag to respective element to hide in HTML (template file)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this npm package: **[NgxHideOnScroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-hide-on-scroll)** to hide the div element when user scrolls down and show that element again when the user scrolls up in Angular.

## [View the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-hide-on-scroll)

---

## Installation

```sh
npm install ngx-hide-on-scroll --save
```

## Usage

### Step 01: Import the NgxHideOnScrollModule to your module.

e.g. **app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import NgxHideOnScrollModule
import { NgxHideOnScrollModule } from 'ngx-hide-on-scroll';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxHideOnScrollModule // Import NgxHideOnScrollModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### Step 02: Add the `ngxHideOnScroll` directive to your element.

e.g. **app.component.html**

```html
<div ngxHideOnScroll [propertyUsedToHide]="'height'" [valueWhenHidden]="'0px'" [valueWhenShown]="'100px'">
  <h2>Navbar</h2>
</div>
```

Feel free to change the value of the attributes: `propertyUsedToHide`, `valueWhenHidden` and `valueWhenShown` according to your needs.

That's it. Have a nice day!